# WHERE to check if NVARCHAR record begins with a number or symbol in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am using a SQL statement to fetch records where name begins with some alphabet

```
SELECT * FROM Music WHERE Title LIKE 'A%' ORDER BY Title
```

Can anyone suggest SQL query which will fetch Title beginning with numbers and symbols?

Comment: What [RDBMS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relational_database_management_system) you are using? `RDBMS` stands for *Relational Database Management System*. `RDBMS is the basis for SQL`, and for all modern database systems like MS SQL Server, IBM DB2, Oracle, MySQL, etc...

Comment: I am using MS-SQL and only ascii characters in Title.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use LIKE with character sets:

```
SELECT * FROM Music WHERE Title LIKE '[^A-Za-z]%' ORDER BY Title
```

Sample:

```
declare @music table(id int identity(1,1) not null primary key, title varchar(10))
insert @music(title)
values
    ('test1'), 
    ('9test'), 
    ('0test'), 
    ('#test')

SELECT * FROM @Music WHERE Title LIKE '[^A-Za-z]%' ORDER BY Title
```

--- results ---

```
id  title
4   #test
3   0test
2   9test
```

Answer (score 2):

use `PATINDEX`

```
SELECT * 
FROM   Music 
WHERE  PATINDEX('[^a-zA-Z]%', Title) = 1
ORDER  BY Title
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/b5df12/2)
- [TSQL Doc: PATINDEX](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188395.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Can do this with PATINDEX function and LEFT Function combined:

```
SELECT *
FROM Music
WHERE PATINDEX('%[A-Z ,a-z]%',LEFT(Title,1)) = 0
```

Edit: Since you're searching for non-alphabet character at start, changed to = 0, = 1 would return any that start with alphabetic character.